# ARC doesn't free memory when using blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having trouble with ARC.
What I do is synchronization: I ask for data from a webservice and I write that to a database (with fmdb).

Here's my full code

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    hud.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sincronizzo le aziende"];
    [Model syncAziende:^(id response, NSError *error) {
        hud.progress += offset;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    hud.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sincronizzo i contatti"];
    [Model syncContatti:^(id response, NSError *error) {
        hud.progress += offset;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

            ....

+ (void)syncAziende:(RequestFinishBlock)completation
{
    [self syncData:^(id response, NSError *error) {
        completation(response,error);
    } wsEndPoint:kCDCEndPointGetAziende tableName:kCDCDBAziendeTableName];
}

+ (void)syncData:(RequestFinishBlock)completation wsEndPoint:(NSString*) url tableName:(NSString *)table
{
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    [self getDataFromWS:^(id WSresponse, NSError* WSError)
     {
         if (!WSError)
             [self writeDatatoDB:^(id DBresponse,NSError* DBError)
              {
                  completation(DBresponse,DBError);
              }table:table shouldDeleteTableBeforeUpdate:YES data:WSresponse];
         else
             completation(nil,WSError);
         WSresponse = nil;
     }WSUrl:url];
}

+ (void)getDataFromWS:(RequestFinishBlock)completation WSUrl:(NSString *)svcUrl
{
    [self getJsonDataFromURL:^(id response, NSError *error)
     {
         completation(response,error);
     }url:svcUrl];
}

+(void)getJsonDataFromURL:(RequestFinishBlock)completation url:(NSString*)url
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [self getAuthorizedRequestionOperationManager];

    if (manager) { //OK I'have internet connection
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

        [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            completation([responseObject objectForKey:@"d"],nil);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            completation(nil,error);
        }];
    }
    else //ERROR: I don't have internet connection
    {
        NSDictionary *dError = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:kCDCErrorNoInternetConnectionStatusMessage,@"error", nil];
        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc]initWithDomain:url code:kCDCErrorNoInternetConnectionStatusCode userInfo:dError];
        completation(nil,error);
    }
}


+ (void) writeDatatoDB:(RequestFinishBlock)completion
                 table:(NSString *)tableName
shouldDeleteTableBeforeUpdate:(BOOL)deleteTable
                  data:(NSMutableArray *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Inizio le operazioni sul database");
    __block int errors = 0;

    classAppDelegate *appDelegate = (classAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:appDelegate.dbFilePath];
    [queue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) {

        if (deleteTable)
            [db executeUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM %@", tableName]];

        for (NSDictionary *jString in data)
        {
            NSMutableArray* cols = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray* vals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (id currentValue in jString)
            {
                if (![currentValue isEqualToString:@"__metadata"]) {
                    [cols addObject:currentValue];
                    [vals addObject:[jString valueForKey:currentValue]];
                }
            }

            NSMutableArray* newCols = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray* newVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSString *value = @"";

            for (int i = 0; i<[cols count]; i++) {
                @try {
                    NSString *element = [vals objectAtIndex:i];
                    if (![element isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                        value = [element stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];
                        [newCols addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'", [cols objectAtIndex:i]]];
                        [newVals addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'", value]];
                    }
                }
                @catch (NSException *exception) {

                }
            }

            NSString* sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ (%@) VALUES (%@)",tableName, [newCols componentsJoinedByString:@", "], [newVals componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
            [db executeUpdate:sql];

            if([db lastErrorCode] == 1) //ERRORE!!
            {
                errors++;
            }
        }
        completion(nil,nil);


        NSLog(@"Ho completato le operazioni sul database con %i errori",errors);
    }];
}
```

The data I get from webservice is about 75mb, but in Xcode I see the memory goes to 500mb which makes an iPad 2 crash.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly did a **retain cycle** in your block.

It happens mostly when you call self in the block. So self is retained in the block and in main sequence. So both are hold each other and ARC think both are needed by the other.

You should use weak self or other method like it.

Here some help : [The Correct Way to Avoid Capturing Self in Blocks With ARC](http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=160)

Comment: Thanks for reply but I don't use self in no where.

Comment: If you use an iVar (e.g. _myLabel), it ends the same.

Comment: If you see the code Model use static methods there is no type of local instance.

Comment: I see a **self** on line 37

Comment: I corrected the code following your suggestions: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7173485/ but nothing changes.

Comment: `+ (void)syncAziende:(RequestFinishBlock)completation
{
    __weak typeof(self)selfObject = self;` I find it weird... it a class method, but you call self ? What are you expecting exactly ?

Comment: [self or [Model is the same thing in this case

Comment: My bad, however I don't see anything else wrong, maybe it's somewhere else in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

libextobjc has some useful macros to help with this problem, see http://aceontech.com/objc/ios/2014/01/10/weakify-a-more-elegant-solution-to-weakself.html